# Manual promotion of pipeline results in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, artifactory, release-management

We are currently moving from our legacy build server to Jenkins.

In our previous system, we had the following system:

1. You don't directly build a release version, but you build a "BETA".
2. After you are satisfied with the result, you can promote the "BETA" to "RELEASE".
3. For that, you click on the build (the actual pipeline run) and click on a button "BETA to RELEASE".
4. This button triggers a script to do the actual promotion (the actual steps are irrelevant for this question).

For Jenkins, I haven't found something like that yet. To be precise: I would like to choose one of the successful builds and then click on some kind of button to promote the results of that build to RELEASE. So even if I have build `1.2.0-BETA`, `1.2.1-BETA` and `1.2.2-BETA`, I can choose `1.2.1-BETA` and release it to `1.2.1`.

What would be a good approach for this?

Comment: Try those: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plug-in
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plugin+-+Release+Management

Comment: @galusben Sorry, I should have mentioned that I know the Artifactory plugin. It is pretty much in the spirit I like, but it does not just add a button, but a whole section of fields from which you choose sources and targets and further properties of your promotion. This means that the developer can (accidentally or intentionally) promote releases to wrong targets or in an otherwise wrong way. If one could reduce this plugin to just a button, this would be great...

Comment: Which options would you like to disable in the Interactive Promotion functionality supported for pipeline jobs?

Comment: @EyalBenMoshe All of them. All should be preconfigured and the developer who runs the pipeline should just click a button (or something similar) without altering any values.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest the following

We can create a Jenkins pipeline for an Application (Ex: API Services). In this API deployment pipeline, there are many stages,

- Get source code from GIT
- Restore the dependent libraries
- Build the solution & generate the deployment artifacts (with suitable version , ex: Beta 1)
- Deploy the artifacts to Dev environment
- We have a wait time (ex: 1 day) using a timeout in Jenkins pipeline
- Once the dev team validates the build and finds that it is suitable for promotion to QA
- they click on Approve
- Approved build gets updated with the version (ex: QA-1)
- Await QA team approval
- Once approved, move to production.

Reference Link: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/

Example Snippet of pipeline code

```
 stage("Validate before Apply") {
                timeout(time:30, unit:'MINUTES') {
                    input 'Are you sure to promote this build to QA?'
                }
            }
```

Comment: This is generally a good idea. But our artifacts can be in BETA for weeks and I don't know whether it is a good idea to keep a running pipeline open that long.

Comment: yes, normally we have a cycle time of approximately 10 days to move to production, or else we can also think of using the `git hooks` to be connected to trigger a build in jenkins. This can be like once the beta version works great, we have to merge the feature to QA, thus a pull-request based merge & commit in github can be used to trigger a new build in the Jenkins Server. In the Jenkins pipeline, we can have a build approval so that even if triggered, the approver should analyze and approve the deployment, though manual, but can be a good option as well

Answer (score 1):

I think that [Promoted Builds Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/promoted-builds/) is what you need.

Basically, after installing the plugin, you create a job that build your BETA version and in its configuration, you set up a promotion, manually approved, that run your promotion script.

Depending of your need, you maybe configure as well the number of days you want to keep the builds of the job.

Comment: Unfortunately the Promoted Builds Plugin still does not support Jenkins pipelines.   There is a ticket for this at https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-36089 but there does not appear to be any progress at time of writing.